# You keep me hanging on

Tags: verbs, phrases, phrasal-verbs

What is actually the phasal verb in a sentence:

You keep me hanging on

"Keep on" or "hang on"? What do we have here? Double phrasal verb? I am trying to figure this out for a while today... This is the part of the song by Vanilla Fudge and others.

Answer (score 1):

The [lyrics](https://www.metrolyrics.com/you-keep-me-hangin-on-lyrics-the-supremes.html) continues as this:

```
    You say although we broke up
You still wanna be just friends
...
'Cause you don't really love me
    You just keep me hangin' on
```

The singer complains that his partner does not love him anymore but she wants him to continue paying attention to her - *to keep him hanging on*.

It is obvious that the preposition **on** refers to the [phrasal verb **hang**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hang-on-upon-sth) and not to *keep*.

If you prefer *Supremes* version to *Vanilla Fudge*, please invert the gender of previous personal pronouns.

Comment: I thought the singer complains, that there is no chemistry from the partner. And she is "one of the others" - like he has other girls who he is interested more with... And just in case she's around. (the Supremes version). So he keeps her hanging on. That was my understanding. With yours I'm more confused. Need to think it over because there is another phrasal verb with hang on which means waiting.